# No intercept term in ordered logistic regression - how do I incorporate dummy variables for three categories?

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, ordered-logit

With OLS regression, when we have three categories (e.g. married, unmarried, divorced) and want to use dummy variables, we use something like this:

[image]

Where if the two d's = 0, beta1 represents e.g. the value for married; when the first d = 1 and the other 0, gamma1 represents the unmarried group, and when the first d = 0 and the other = 1, gamma2 represents the divorced group.

However, when we use ordered logistic regression, the output in statistical software does not include an intercept term. E.g. you get something that looks like:

[image]

So, my question is how do I represent a three category situation with dummies as the independent variables when using ordered logistic regression since there's no intercept term?

Thanks!

Comment: All the software I've seen does give you two intercepts for a three-category outcome: R's implementations in the MASS and VGAM packages, Stata's `-ologit-`, SAS `PROC LOGISTIC'.  They are usually in a separate subtable, but they are there

Comment: @ThomasLumley thanks for letting me know. I'm using Stata, so I suppose it must be in a separate subtable?

Comment: Here's an an annotated example: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/output/ordered-logistic-regression/

Comment: @ThomasLumley thanks, that looks similar to my output, but again, I don't see the intercept? By intercept I'm referring to '_cons'. Do you know what the equivalent is in the link you sent?

Comment: They are the `_cut1` and `cut2`.  `cut1` is the intercept in the (2&3) vs 1 regression and `_cut2` is the intercept in the 3 vs (2&1) regression